# Reference request: equivalent definitions of uniform convexity

Tags: reference-request, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space), one can choose either the unit ball or the unit sphere in the definition of uniform convexity, and the resulting definitions are equivalent. This is backed up by a proof.

I have made use of this equivalence in an article, and would like to simply add a reference, since the proof is a little tedious to repeat verbatim.

Has anyone come across this result in a textbook or article?

I have tried Rudin, Brezis, Bogachev, Conway, the book "Functional analysis and infinite dimensional geometry", and the paper on uniform convexity by Ringrose (cited in the Wikipedia article), as well searching online and asking a few colleagues, but I have not found anything resembling the result I'm after.

Comment: I had a look at the Wikipedia page. When the proof was added, no additional reference was included. It's possible that it's simply original research, or folklore (or that the person who added it was too lazy to add a citation).